# Show dialog some time get "Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState"

Tags: android

I already read this questions 
[On showing dialog i get "Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15729138/on-showing-dialog-i-get-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsaveinstancestate)

[Show DialogFragment when user clicks deny on Runtime permissions dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33181952/show-dialogfragment-when-user-clicks-deny-on-runtime-permissions-dialog)

But I still don't known how to slove this? Any one help me? If the information is not enough and detail, I will provide more!

Here is the complete stack trace of the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onBackPressed(FragmentActivity.java)
    at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2531)
    at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2731)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2784)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java)
    at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2402)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4659)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4615)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4110)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4163)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4129)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4293)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4137)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4350)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4110)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4163)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4129)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4137)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4110)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4163)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4129)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4326)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4496)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2330)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1934)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1925)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2307)
    at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:328)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5769)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

and trace the [image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If the dialog you're trying to show is a DialogFragment then you must have called like this

```
messageDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), TAG);
```

You can instead do the following:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(this, tag);
ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
messageDialogFragment.show(ft, TAG);
```

You'll never have the error Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState"
but as stated in this great article http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html, this is the last resort. The article explains in depth your problem.

Comment: ChooseSIMDialogActivity is extends AppCompatActivity, any idea for that.